# replacing first character in a string with multiple characters using its index

Tags: php

A **string** like (for **example**):

```
$s = "allo";
```

i wanted to replace its first character with `he` to become `hello` using the indexes, so i used

```
$s = "allo";
$s[0] = "he";
echo $s;
```

the result i expected was `hello` but got `hllo`

is there a kind of a **limit** on changing the letters by indexes in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a string as an array, you are referencing individual characters, so `$s[0]` is the `a`, trying to fit two charachters into 1 isn't going to work.  The easiest way to do it is to take the new string and append the old value from the second position (I've used `substr($s,1)`)

```
$s = "alalo";
$res = "he".substr($s,1);
echo $res;
```

gives...

```
helalo
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP a string can be formed  using index  on the string itself without problem but You can't use  $s[0] = "he"; because this way you are trying to assing to a single location two char .. so php assign just the first  .. for change both the chars  you must use the replace function.

You could try using replace

```
 $res = str_replace($s[0], "he" ,$s );
```

But ass  suggested  by Nigel Ren this work if there only an occurrence of the $s[0] in the $s string  otherwise you use a string concat and substring instead  of a replace

Comment: because  You want assign  on index  element two values . .$s[0]  in a char position  (is the memory location for a char  not for two).